# Как заставить блок title использовать только свободное пространство?

Tags: html, css

Блок находится в блоке, шириной в 100%. При заполнении блока title очень длинным текстом, и отмене переноса строк, он расширяется до 100%, переносится на новую строку и следующие за ним блоки тоже переносятся.

```css
.month-num, .title {
  float: left;
}

.persone, .start-date, .end-date {
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class=month>
  <div class=month-num>2</div>
  <div class=title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
  <div class=persone>geqo</div>
  <div class=start-date>21.11.12</div>
  <div class=end-date>22.11.12</div>
  <div class=clear></div>
</div>
```

Как заставить использовать его только свободное пространство, не указывая фиксированную ширину у других блоков?

[image: html, css - result]

Comment: не отменять перенос строк

Comment: Для того, чтоб скрывался лишний текст, у блока должна быть указана ширина. У этого блока ширины нет, поэтому он расширяется до 100%. Отмена запрета переноса строк никак не поможет.

Comment: Можете вместо изображений написать код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без применения флексбокса, «по-старому», этого добивались при помощи комбинации оберток с `float: left / right` + `overflow: hidden`.

Чтобы увидеть резиновость решения, разверните на весь экран и подвигайте край окна браузера.

```css
.month-num {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.persone, .start-date, .end-date {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.month__wrap-left {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.month__wrap-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class=month>
  <div class=month__wrap-right>
    <div class=persone>geqo</div>
    <div class=start-date>21.11.12</div>
    <div class=end-date>22.11.12</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class=month__wrap-left>
    <div class=month-num>2</div>
    <div class=title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class=clear></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли. Пока же было реализовано через @media-запросы с жесткими размерами.